# Python itemgetter to sort dict based on middle of value string

Tags: python

I created a dictionary:

```
listing = {'2': 'Mary Lejam', '3': 'Zachery Aka', '1': 'John Joer', '4': 'Joe Private', '10': 'Carla Chris'}
```

I'm writing a simple program that sorts the names according to the keys (which are the id) and sort according to last name
I figure out the id one with the keys of the dictionary. But now i'm trying to find a way to sort the last name.

1. if i do listing.values(), it sorts with the first letter of the first name
2. if i use the itemgetter, i can only put an index that it will sort with.

I tried importing re, such as `itemgetter(re.match(regex))`, gives me error
I was wondering if it is possible to use itemgetter and write some regex inside it to ignore everything before the last name. It would ignore everything before the space basically.

```
LastName = sorted(listing.values(), key=itemgetter(Some Regex))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itemgetter` isn't particularly useful here, because you need to do further work on the return value, and Python doesn't have any way to compose functions directly.

```
sorted(listing.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].split()[1])
```

---

If there *were* function composition, say, because you are using the `toolz` package, you might write

```
from toolz import compose

# Equivalent functions, but names reflect different *purposes*
get_name = get_last_name = itemgetter(1)
split_name = methodcaller('split')

sorted(listing.items(), key=compose(get_last_name, split_name, get_name))
```

Comment: Did you mean `x['1']` instead of `x[1]`?

Comment: No, because `x` here is a tuple like `('1', 'John Joer')`. `x[1]` is the last name in the tuple.

Comment: Thank you!, So if i understand correctly, the values of the dictionary is composed of tuple and i can get the index 1 of the tuple which represent the last name

Comment: Not the dictionary itself; the iterator returned by `listing.items()`. If you used `sorted(listing)`, you would just get back the list of sorted *keys*.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split and reassemble:

```
listing = {'2': 'Mary Lejam', '3': 'Zachery Aka', '1': 'John Joer', '4': 'Joe Private', '10': 'Carla Chris'}

import operator
sorted(({k:[v.split(' ')[1], v.split(' ')[0]] for k,v in listing.items()}).items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

[('3', ['Aka', 'Zachery']),
 ('10', ['Chris', 'Carla']),
 ('1', ['Joer', 'John']),
 ('2', ['Lejam', 'Mary']),
 ('4', ['Private', 'Joe'])]

listing = {i[0]:' '.join([i[1][1], i[1][0]]) for i in temp}

{'3': 'Zachery Aka',
 '10': 'Carla Chris',
 '1': 'John Joer',
 '2': 'Mary Lejam',
 '4': 'Joe Private'}
```

But in general [Python dictionaries are unsorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value), if you really need a sorted data structure you shouldn't be using a dict.